# Textarea: pressing enter creates new line

Tags: php, textarea

When I press enter in the textarea it goes to a new line, but that new line does not show up when the textarea is submitted. How do I make this work? It should be simple, but from what I have searched and tried has failed.

```
<textarea style="{ white-space:pre; }"; name="texts" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>

$texts = $_POST['texts'];
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Comment: I'd prefer to use PHP to make it work, but anything to make it work is fine.

Comment: New-line characters are white-space chars so you wouldn't necessarily see them in a simple `var_dump` or `echo`

Comment: Do you run any editing on your text? Something that could remove "\r\n" symbols?

Comment: How would the code look for that to work?

Comment: [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Comment: Nope.  Check out the bottom of this page http://www.vidyasocks.com/forums.php?id=2&id=2 When you type something in and create a new line with enter the text will show up on the same line. Only reason it worked on the last two is because I put <br /> as a string replace.

Comment: How are you displaying the contents that were posted from the textarea? Maybe you need to do an nl2br? http://nl3.php.net/nl2br

Comment: What do you mean by "does not show up when the textarea is submitted"? How have you checked?

Comment: I am displaying them as $texts = $_POST['texts'];  How do I nl2br?

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for the `nl2br()` function.

[nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the issue is that the new line is showing up, but you're outputing it as html, so it doesn't conserve that new line. You need to convert newlines to break tags when you output as html. You can do it like so:

```
//editing per comment advice. Apparently this method shouldn't be used since it doesn't replace all possible newline representations, although I dont remember having an issue with it.
//$string = str_replace("\n", "<br />", $string);
//as others mentioned, this is better and easier:
$string = nl2br($string);
```

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question, but this is what I took from it.

Comment: [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/nl2br) is probably preferred in this case. Edit: Not the downvoter.. this answer is definitely useful :)

Comment: fair enough :) What is the difference, nl2br converts \r\n as well? Edit: nvm, read the doc.